# How to declare variable outside loop and set some values in loop in XSL?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

In my case,

I have to use a variable outside loop with some default values and in loop I have to set it to some values.

How do I achieve this? Please let me know the solution.

Sample code(that I have used):

```
 <xsl:variable name="flagforselectedOption" select="'true'"/>
    <xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="">
        <xsl:variable name="flagforselectedOption" select="'true'"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>
```

It doesn't work for me. Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

With XSLT variables are immutable, i.e. you cannot change their value once set. This means that you have to re-think the logic of your transform.

Answer (score 0):

Describe your problem: the input XML, the output XML, and how they relate to each other. Then we can explain how to do it in a functional, declarative language like XSLT. Reverse engineering your requirement from code that doesn't work isn't possible.